# Conditional Statement Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

I'm wondering what the following is evaluating to on each iteration, I've checked the internet but can't find any definite answers

And also if there's anymore efficient ways to do it.

```
for i in range(0, len(c)):
    if i & True:
           pass
```

Comment: The `&` is a [bitwise operator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).

Comment: Are you asking what the code is doing? Because that code is not doing anything except counting from 0 to c.

The ```if i & True:``` is equivalent to writing ```if i:```. In the greater context of the loop, ```i``` will evaluate to True for non-zero, so you could rewrite the loop as ```for i in range(1, len(c)):```

Comment: @TomLubenow no sorry i mean what's it evaluating to, code will be included within it

Comment: @AndersonGreen what's it comparing on each iteration?

Comment: @AlexR: Saying ```& True``` is useless in a condition. Since you know ```i``` is numeric, in python numbers are True in conditions if they are non-zero.

Comment: @TomLubenow You're thinking of `i and True`. `&` is a bit-wise operator, not a logical operator.

Comment: @TomLubenow no @ Barman is correct as i will evaluate to true if it’s 1 or false if it’s 0

Comment: Oh my mistake. I was doing my arithmetic wrong, treating it as a bitwise OR. I consider doing arithmetic on booleans unpythonic, I'd recommend @bihsing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`True` has an integer value of `1` in Python, so when the loop iterates an integer `i` from `0` to the length of `c` and performs bitwise-and on `i` and `1`, it effectively checks if `i` is an odd number and if so, executes the `pass` statement (where I believe there are more code in your real code).

As for a more efficient way to do it, instead of generating all the numbers between 0 and the length of `c` and filtering out even numbers, you can use the `step` parameter of the `range` function to generate the desired sequence of odd numbers in the first place:

```
for i in range(1, len(c), 2):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

`i & True` evaluates to `0` for even numbers and `1` for odd numbers.

```
for i in range(0, 5): 
    print(i, i & True)
```

yields:

```
(0, 0)
(1, 1)
(2, 0)
(3, 1)
(4, 0)
```